# jQuery scrollbar issue when adding/removing DOM elements

Tags: jquery

In my webpage, every image is displayed as a thumbnail. When the image is clicked on, it hides itself and creates a larger version of the same image as a sibling. When clicked again, the larger sibling is hidden and the thumbnail is shown again.

So an expand/collapse function.

The problem is: when the larger image is created the scrollbar shrinks to make room, but when the larger image is removed the scrollbar doesn't grow back to its original height.

Code:

```
// Image Expansion //

$(document).on("click","a[data-cmd='image-expand']", function(e){ //Expand call
    Images.expand(e);
});
$(document).on("click","a[data-cmd='image-collapse']", function(e){ //Collapse call
    Images.collapse(e);
});

var Images = {};

Images.expand = function(e){
    var link = $(e.currentTarget); //The clickable link
    var img = link.children('img'); //Thumbnail image

    var disp = document.createElement('img'); //Larger image created
    $(disp).attr('src', img.attr('src'));

    link.attr('data-cmd', 'image-collapse'); //Change link function
    img.css('display', 'none'); //Hide thumb
    $(disp).appendTo(link); //Place large img 
};

Images.collapse = function(e){
    var link = $(e.currentTarget); //The clickable link
    var img = link.children('img').last(); //Larger image

    link.attr('data-cmd', 'image-expand'); //Change link function
    img.remove(); //Remove large img
    link.children('img').show(); //Show thumb
};
```

Here is what I mean in pictures:

Before expansion:
[image: before]

During expansion (notice smaller scrollbar):
[image: during]

After collapsing (notice scrollbar size is the same as 2nd image)
[image: after]

P.S. Title is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500791/jquery-adding-removing-dom-elements-scrollbar-issue), but asking for different answer.

Comment: Post relevant code in question itself